# Unable to render {message} object in the Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, google-chrome

I am using `{message}` from the props in a component in the ReactJS.

The code is given below

```
import React from "react";

const MyMessage = ({ message }) => {
  if (message?.attachments?.length > 0) {
    return (
      <img
        src={message.attachments[0].file}
        alt="message_attachment"
        className="message-image"
        style={{ float: "right" }}
      />
    );
  }


  const msg = JSON.stringify(message);
  console.log("fmsg = "+ msg.sender)
  console.log("mes = "+JSON.stringify(message))
  console.log("now = "+msg.first_name)
  return (
    <div
      className="message"
      style={{
        float: "right",
        marginRight: "18px",
        color: "white",
        backgroundColor: "#3B2A50",
      }}
    >
      {message?.text}
      
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyMessage;
```

### What I tried?

I used the following console stmts:

- console.log(message); ->  `[Object Object]`
- console.log(JSON.stringify(message));

  ```
  {
    "id":455890,
    "sender":{
      "username":"GMmohit",
      "first_name":"Mohit",
      "last_name":"Maroliya",
      "avatar":"https://api-chat-engine-io.s3.amazonaws.com/avatars/potrait_rKDI2hb.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAZA5RH3EC2MM47GFP%2F20220213%2Fca-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220213T141431Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=1d5e0ec2418701210532824ba90af5f6366d17b7fa1f9dfadb6783cd8efdbfd6",
      "custom_json":"{}",
      "is_online":true
    },
    "created":"2022-02-12 12:23:04.745937+00:00",
    "attachments":[],
    "sender_username":"undefined",
    "text":"----",
    "custom_json":"{}"
  }
  ```
- const msg = JSON.stringify(message)
  console.log("now = "+msg.first_name)  `-> but it gives undefined`

How can I access the values in `{message}` like `username`,`first_name` etc? However, I am able to access `message?.text` .

Comment: Once you've called `JSON.stringify(message)` you cannot access fields via `msg`, which is going to be a plain string. That should be `message.first_name`.

Comment: Then how can I access that mentioned field?

Comment: Look, `msg` is a **string**.  That's what `JSON.stringify()` returns (hence its name).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your username and first name are coming off the sender object in your message. You'll need to consider the sender like:
 `message.sender.username`
to access the username that is in the sender object in the message.

Answer (score 1):

If you are stringifying your json, you will not be able to take data from it, because it will serve as a whole string not as an object.